# Change css Microsoft Translator Web Page Widget

Tags: css, widget, microsoft-translator

I include the MS translator web page widget in one page of my web app.

This is the code:

```
<span id='MicrosoftTranslatorWidget' class='Dark' style='color:white;background-color:#000;'></span>

   <script type='text/javascript'>
   setTimeout(function(){{
      var s=document.createElement('script');
      s.type='text/javascript';
      s.charset='UTF-8';
      s.src=((location && location.href && location.href.indexOf('https') == 0)?'https://ssl.microsofttranslator.com':'http://www.microsofttranslator.com')+'/ajax/v3/WidgetV3.ashx?siteData=ueOIGRSKkd965FeEGM5JtQ**&ctf=False&ui=true&settings=Manual&from=en';
      var p=document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]||document.documentElement;
      p.insertBefore(s,p.firstChild); }},0);
   </script>
```

It works, but Microsoft use two css (`WidgetLauncher.css` and `WidgetV3.css`) from http://www.microsofttranslator.com/static/187544/css/
called after my css, so it's useless to change some css properties values.

Does a possible solution exist?

Answer (score 1):

any css marked as !important will override those css files. Have you tried that?

```
#LauncherTranslatePhrase{
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: Yes. Also MS css defines some properties as !important. But the "strange" thing is that if I see the html code, the extern css is included before mine.

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you were more specific about what styles you want to change, because different parts of the control are styled in different ways.

For example the background color of the button is set as an inline style via javascript, but the initial value is controlled by the `background-color` property on the span with id *MicrosoftTranslatorWidget* (which you've already set as black).

```html
<span id='MicrosoftTranslatorWidget' class='Dark'
  style='color:white;background-color:#000;'></span>
```

Instead of using an inline style, you could have also set that in your stylesheet like this:

```css
#MicrosoftTranslatorWidget {
  background-color:#000;
}
```

The text color on the button is more complicated to override. It's set in Microsoft's stylesheet via the selector `#MicrosoftTranslatorWidget *`. To override that style, you would need to use [a more specific selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity), e.g. something like this:

```css
span#MicrosoftTranslatorWidget * {                       
  color:white;
}
```

You could also use an [`!important`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#important-rules) rule, as suggested by *projeqht* and *Facundo Colombier*, but that's usually best left as a last resort, and won't always be enough anyway.

For example, the hover background color is set via the `.TranslatePhrase:hover` selector, but it is already using an `!important` rule, so that won't be enough to override it. You need to use a selector with higher specificity as well as an `!important` rule to make your style take precedence.

```css
div.TranslatePhrase:hover {
  background-color:blue !important;
}
```

In general, you first need to use your browser's Web inspector to determine the CSS selector that is being used to set a particular property. Then you can override it with your own selector by using a higher specificity and, if necessary, an `!important` rule.

For help with calculating (and understanding) the specificity of CSS selectors, I highly recommend Keegan Street's [Specificity Calculator](http://specificity.keegan.st/).

Answer (score 1):

Can you use a javascript solution? If so, then use code like this to manipulate the style of the element directly. Rules defined this way override anything from a stylesheet, even `!important` specificity.

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("MicrosoftTranslaterWidget").style.backgroundColor = red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be much support for the Microsoft Translator Widget.

Here are some links that might be useful:

- Developers - http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/translator/developers.aspx
- API - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd576287.aspx
- Web Widget API - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn341983.aspx

Also, Microsoft support (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e389bff3-fbd3-4405-82ca-71a03b66c2eb/design-the-ms-translater-widget) mentioned:

> If you need significantly more customizability, you can always use the AJAX API (which is what the widget is built on top of).

So you might be able to do customize the widget using the AJAX API, although that post was quite old (2009).

- AJAX API - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff512385.aspx

As ugly as it seems, you might be better off using **`!important`** if you need to overwrite CSS properties.